# How to adjust Uiimage height and width ratio

Tags: ipad

i am working on a project in which i have to cropped image and save cropped image in photo library. I have got success in cropping image but problem is that when i cropped image and show it ,it is stretched .i am also using aspect fit mode. But still its stretched.Here is the code

```
-(void)cropLassoArea {

isLassoSelected = NO;
lassoStyle = 0;
CGRect frame;
frame = mainImageView.frame;
mainImageView.frame.size = CroppedImage.size;
for (int i = 0; i < [lassoArray count]; i++) {

    CAShapeLayer *layer = [lassoArray objectAtIndex:i];

    CGPathRef myPath = layer.path;
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mainImageView.frame.size);

    [mainImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];


   [mainImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,CroppedImage.size.width,CroppedImage.size.height)]; 

    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextAddPath(context, myPath);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
    CGContextEOFillPath(context);

    mainImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to download files from [this](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) location and I suggest you to go through their tutorial. Its easy and it won't stretch your image at all. I have used these files in one of my working project. You just need to import their header file and call following lines

```
    UIImage *tmpImage = [yourImageView.image resizedImage:CGSizeMake(desiredWidth,DesiredHeight) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
    yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    [yourImageView setImage:tmpImage];
```

Hope it helps.